# code after var fs = require('fs') not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Why does my simple jquery not run after the var fs = require('fs') code.

This runs correctly

```
    //here is my simple jquery
    $("#table th").css("color", "yellow");
//here starts the fs code
        var fs = require('fs');
        var output = fs.readFileSync('component names.txt', 'utf8').replace(/(\r)/gm, "").split('\n').map((line) => {
            let [Eng, Spa, ger] = line.split('\t');
            return {
                Eng,
                Spa,
                ger
            };
        });
        var Eng = output.map(item => item.Eng);
        var Spa = output.map(item => item.Spa);
```

However if I put the $("#table th").css("color", "yellow") at the bottom, where I want it because I'm going to populate a table, it doesn't work here:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var output = fs.readFileSync('component names.txt', 'utf8').replace(/(\r)/gm, "").split('\n').map((line) => {
    let [Eng, Spa, ger] = line.split('\t');
    return {
        Eng,
        Spa,
        ger
    };
});
var Eng = output.map(item => item.Eng);
var Spa = output.map(item => item.Spa);

//jquery
$("#table th").css("color", "yellow");
```

Why?

Comment: If you are not rendering server-side then your "jquery" (please say Javascript) is running client-side but fs node package is server-side (is it?)

Comment: I first built my fs code using the terminal to print out my console.log of my array. Now that works I'm going to add the array to html. So I'm not sure what needs to be done, to create a local host or not @AdrianoRepetti

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it having something to do with the `readFileSync` function.
Try wrapping it with a try catch, see if it catches anything. 
You said that the first code works, but I think you were referring to the jquery code. I believe that the fs code is not functioning properly.

```
try {

  var output = fs.readFileSync('component names.txt', 'utf8').replace(/(\r)/gm, "").split('\n').map((line) => {
  let [Eng, Spa, ger] = line.split('\t');
    return {
      Eng,
      Spa,
      ger
    };
  });


  var Eng = output.map(item => item.Eng);
  var Spa = output.map(item => item.Spa);

} catch(e) {
  console.error(e) //see what's going on here
}
```

If you do this, the jquery code will work, because whatever error is happening will be caught and ignored, so it's very important to debug the code to not run into any future problems

Comment: I don't have any errors following your try method. vars Eng and Spa print out an array in the console.log correctly.